# Can the ideal $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n) $ be generated by fewer polynomials over the field $K[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

My algebra teacher asked whether the ideal $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n) $ can be generated by fewer polynomials over the field $K[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n]$.

My intuition tells me that it can't, so I tried to suppose the opposite.
If it could, then there would be $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_{n-1} \in K[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n]$ such that $(P_1, P_2, \dots, P_{n-1}) = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$ (if fewer than n-1 polynomials suffice, I could just pick some more out of ${X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n}$).

It follows that there are some polynomials $Q_{ij} \in K[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n],\space i \in \{1, \dots n\},\space j \in \{1, \dots n-1\}$ such that:

$P_1 \times Q_{1,1} + P_2 \times Q_{1,2} + \dots + P_{n-1} \times Q_{1,n-1} = X_1$

$\dots$

$P_1 \times Q_{n,1} + P_2 \times Q_{n,2} + \dots + P_{n-1} \times Q_{n,n-1} = X_n$

Here I kinda got stuck so I would appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Denote the ideal $\left(X_1,X_2,...,X_n\right)$ by $M$, and the ring $K\left[X_1,X_2,...,X_n\right]$ by $A$. Then, $M/M^2$ is an $A/M$-vector space (this is a general fact, and proven completely straightforwardly) of dimension $n$. (The ring $A/M$ is a field and isomorphic to $K$.) Now what would happen if you had $n-1$ generators for $M$?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422182/number-of-generators-of-the-maximal-ideals-in-polynomial-rings-over-a-field

Comment: Somehow related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95004/every-ideal-of-kx-1-ldots-x-n-has-leq-n-generators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your intuition is right: The ideal $\left(X_1,X_2,...,X_n\right)$ of $K\left[X_1,X_2,...,X_n\right]$ cannot be generated by less than $n$ elements.

*Proof:* Let $M$ be the ideal $\left(X_1,X_2,...,X_n\right)$ of $K\left[X_1,X_2,...,X_n\right]$. We need to show that this ideal $M$ cannot be generated by less than $n$ elements.

Assume the contrary. That is, the ideal $M$ can be generated by less than $n$ elements. In other words, the $R$-module $M$ can be generated by less than $n$ elements.

But the ring $R/M$ is isomorphic to the field $K$ (why?), hence a field. Thus, $R/M$-modules are $R/M$-vector spaces.

Generally, if $I$ and $J$ are two ideals of a commutative ring $R$, then $J/IJ$ is an $R/I$-module (with the action defined in an obvious way: $\overline r \cdot \overline j = \overline{rj}$, where $\overline r$ means the residue class of $r\in R$ modulo $I$, where $\overline j$ means the residue cass of $j\in J$ modulo $IJ$, and where $\overline{rj}$ means the residue class of $rj\in J$ modulo $IJ$). Applied to $R = K\left[X_1,X_2,...,X_n\right]$, $I = M$ and $J = M$, this yields that $M/M^2$ is an $R/M$-module. Since the $R$-module $M$ can be generated by less than $n$ elements, the $R/M$-module $M/M^2$ can be generated by less than $n$ elements (for instance, the projections of the less than $n$ generators of $M$ onto $M/M^2$). Since $R/M$-modules are $R/M$-vector spaces, this rewrites as follows: The $R/M$-vector space $M/M^2$ has dimension $< n$. Hence, its $n$ elements $\overline{X_1}$, $\overline{X_2}$, ..., $\overline{X_n}$ are linearly dependent (over $R/M$). In other words, there exist elements $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$ of $R$ such that $a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + ... + a_nX_n \in M^2$ but not all of $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$ lie in $M$ (why?). Consider such elements.

Since $a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + ... + a_nX_n \in M^2$, the coefficient of $a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + ... + a_nX_n$ before $X_1$ equals $0$ (because every polynomial in $M^2$ has its coefficient before $X_1$ equal $0$). But the coefficient of $a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + ... + a_nX_n$ before $X_1$ is clearly $a_1\left(0\right)$ (since the only term in the sum $a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + ... + a_nX_n$ which can contribute to the coefficient before $X_1$ is the first term). Thus, $a_1\left(0\right) = 0$. In other words, $a_1 \in M$ (since $M$ is the set of all $P\in K\left[X_1,X_2,...,X_n\right]$ satisfying $P\left(0\right)=0$). Similarly, $a_i \in M$ for all $i\in\left\lbrace 1,2,...,n\right\rbrace$. Thus, all of $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$ lie in $M$. This contradicts the fact that not all $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$ lie in $M$. This contradiction finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Say $P$, $P_1$, $\ldots$, $P_m$ are polynomials in the ideal $(X_1, \ldots, X_m)$ ( no free term) and we have the equality
$$P = Q_1 P_1 + \cdots + Q_m P_m$$
for some polynomials $Q_i$.  Looking at the linear parts ( of degree $1$), we get from the above
$$l(P) = \sum q_i l(P_i)$$
where $q_i$ are the free terms of $Q_i$.

Therefore, if the polynomials $P_i$ in $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ generate the ideal $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ then every linear form $\sum a_j X_j$ is a linear combination of the $l(P_i)$'s.