# Number of generators of the maximal ideals in polynomial rings over a field

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Hi I'm trying to prove the following

> If $K$ is a field (not necessary algebraically closed) then every maximal ideal of $K[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ is generated by exactly $n$ elements.

I know that if $K$ is algebraically closed by Hilbert basis the problem is done. But if $K$ is not algebraic closed, I know that the Krull dimension of
$K[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ is $n$ and by the generalized Krull theorem we have that every ideal has height at most $n$, but I'm stucked in this point.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26497/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-kx1-xn).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need to use any dimension theory. Rather, the proof is by induction. The case $n = 1$ is well known, so I won't repeat it here.

Now, suppose $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $A = K [x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. By a generalised Nullstellensatz, we know that $A / \mathfrak{m}$ is a finite field extension of $K$; in particular, the image of $x_n$ in $A / \mathfrak{m}$ has some minimal polynomial $f_n (t)$ over $K$. Clearly, $f_n (x_n) \in \mathfrak{m}$. Let $L = K[x_n] / (f_n (x_n))$. Then $A / \mathfrak{m} \cong L[x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}] / \mathfrak{n}$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n}$ of $L [x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}]$. Using the induction hypothesis, we know that $\mathfrak{n}$ is generated by $n - 1$ elements, say $f_1 (x_1, \ldots, x_n), f_2 (x_2, \ldots, x_n), \ldots, f_{n-1} (x_{n-1}, x_n)$. Then $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated by $f_1 (x_1, \ldots, x_n), f_2 (x_2, \ldots, x_n), \ldots, f_n (x_n)$, because $K [x_1, \ldots, x_n] / (f_n (x_n)) \cong L [x_2, \ldots, x_n]$.

Comment: I can't see why $A/m$ is  isormophic to $L[x_{1},...,x_{n-1}]/N$ for some N maximal of $L[x_{1},...,x_{n-1}]$. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It essentially follows from the isomorphism right at the end: use the correspondence theorem for ideals of a ring.

Comment: It seems to me that this proof doesn't show why a maximal ideal can't have less than $n$ generators. (Of course, it follows easily from height reasons, but even so I think should have been stated explicitly.)